# Resampling Audio With NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio, resampling

I would like to resample a IEEE floating point ISampleProvider at 44100Hz and get another ISampleProvider at 16000Hz, but I can't seem to get NAudio to do the conversion.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
var myReader = new AudioFileReader(filename);
var resampledAudio = new WaveToSampleProvider( 
                          new MediaFoundationResampler(
                               new SampleToWaveProvider(myReader),
                               new WaveFormat(16000, 2)){ ResamplerQuality = 60 });
```

When I run this code I get an `ArgumentException` with a message saying:

> the input argument must already be floating point

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should solve your problem using this:

```
WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(16000, 2);
```

Instead of:

```
new WaveFormat(16000, 2)
```